# explicit 'this' binding precedence vs implicit 'this' binding precedence

Tags: javascript

I'm reading "this & object prototype" by Kylie Simpson. The author says that explicit binding have a higher precedence than implicit.

I understand that "obj1.foo()" is the implicit binding and that "obj1.foo(obj2) is the explicit binding.

However, if implicit is higher, I do not understand how the last 2 lines result in that?

```
function foo()  console.log( this.a );
var obj1 = { a: 2, foo: foo };
var obj2 = { a: 3, foo: foo };

obj1.foo(); // 2
obj2.foo(); // 3
obj1.foo.call( obj2 ); // 3
obj2.foo.call( obj1 ); // 2
```

Ok, reading of such an expression : obj1.foo.call(obj2) , i think, according to that book, that there is two way to resolve the "this".
First : explicit binding. obj2 is forced to be the context of foo.
Second : implicit binding, obj1 is the context of the function following the dot in "obj1 dot xxxxxx", and the "this" of that function is obj1.

I mean, i was thinking that there is no logical way to determine if we choose "explicit first" or "implicit first". It is a "convention".
I hope it is more clear.

Comment: Personally I don't think Kyle's use of the word "precedence" makes sense, as there's no ordering or selection involved.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you, but -- the point is that `obj1.foo.call(obj2)` is equivalent to something like `obj2.tmp = obj.foo; obj2.tmp()`. So the `this` will be `obj2`, not `obj1`.

Comment: I think by higher "precedence" it means that when using `call(thisArg)`, `thisArg` takes priority over the `this` implicitly bound by just doing `obj.foo()` - which is to be expected...

Comment: If "*the author says that explicit binding have a higher precedence than implicit*", then implicit is **not** higher?

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword is overridden in the last 2 statements via the native `call` method for `foo` of the respective objects. The first parameter specified for `call` is the reference that `this` will be in the scope of `foo`. The other arguments for `call` that aren't there are just passed as parameters to `foo`. Thus, with `call`, the bound reference is not really prioritized, but rather replaced entirely *for that function call only*. Respectively, those last 2 statements are just the same as:

```
obj2.foo();
obj1.foo();
```

Comment: ok, this is if you take the rule "explicit binding" first to evaluate.